# Need to Use a "VLOOKUP" Type of Operation on SQL Query That Finds Multiple Foreign Key Values- SOS

Tags: sql, oracle, join, vlookup

I am running a relatively basic query that finds pallet location information in a warehouse. The query finds the locn_id (foreign key) value for the current and destination location. the locn_id is just a DB ID and has a Display Value associated with it in a different table that I need to add to the query. However, I don't know how to join the table multiple times (once for each column)..

Essentially what I need to happen is similar to an Excel VLOOKUP funtion. I need a solution that can look at my query, take the locn_id value from the two columns and provide me with the dsp_locn value from a different table. Is this possible?

This is the current query:

```
    Select lpn.prev_sub_locn_id "PREV LOCATION", lpn.dest_sub_locn_id "DEST LOCATION"
    FROM LPN_DETAIL
    INNER JOIN LPN ON LPN.LPN_ID = LPN_DETAIL.LPN_ID
    and LPN_FACILITY_STATUS = '50' and lpn.prev_sub_locn_id is not null;
```

Outputs:

```
    PREV LOCATION DEST LOCATION
    0102308       0085795
    0099674       0083978
    0098148       0082971
    0096834       0081068
    0096822       0080925
    0096931       0081502
    0096081       0078225
```

These values however are useless since they are only DB id's. I need a column in the query that will show the dsp_locn value found in the LOCN_HDR table below:

Outputs for LOCN_HDR table:

```
    LOCN_ID  DSP_LOCN
    0067714 C-E-091-A-1
    0067715 C-E-091-A-2
    0067717 C-E-091-B-1
    0067718 C-E-091-B-2
    0067726 C-E-093-A-1
```

Disclaimer, I am newish to SQL still so please try to keep it basic. I am also not able to be creating new tables in the DB. Any questions I'll be sure to respond. This is on Oracle SQL Server. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Show us some sample table data too. (Matching)

Comment: I'm mildly curious; you seem to know how to use INNER JOIN because your query has one already, and a join is effectively VLOOKUP  - is the lightbulb moment that you're missing simply "did you know you can put more than one join into a query" ? (and also, after that, "did you know you can join the same table into a query more than once" ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, you sould include a join for each location in order to get its description. I assume there is always a description for any location.

```
Select ORIGIN_LOC.DSP_LOCN "PREV LOCATION", DESTINATION_LOC.DSP_LOCN "DEST LOCATION"
FROM LPN_DETAIL
INNER JOIN LPN ON LPN.LPN_ID = LPN_DETAIL.LPN_ID
INNER JOIN LOCN_HDR AS ORIGIN_LOC ON ORIGIN_LOC.LOCN_ID = lpn.prev_sub_locn_id
INNER JOIN LOCN_HDR AS DESTINATION_LOC ON DESTINATION_LOC.LOCN_ID = lpn.dest_sub_locn_id
and LPN_FACILITY_STATUS = '50' and lpn.prev_sub_locn_id is not null;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Indeed, and the crucial point that David's post makes is that the same table can be joined into a query over and over again, as many times as there are columns to join, if needs be. If a `tblPerson` had several columns eg `homeAddressId, workAddressId, holidayHomeAddressId, schoolAddressId, correspondenceAddressId, bankingAddressId, parent1AddressId, parent2AddressId...` then you really could join the address table in *eight* times, to all the different IDs, to get all the different addresses on one row